# Create KO Binding Handlers for kendo Scheduler Update / Re-Assign

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, knockout-kendo

I'm using [Knockout-kendo.js binding for **Kendo Scheduler**](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Scheduler.html) in my project.

In Scheduler i'm using [Horizontal Grouping](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources-grouping-horizontal) as well. So, here i have used `DataSource and well as Resources with group.`

**I have declared my Variable like below:**

```
monitorData = ko.observableArray(),

schedulerData = ko.observableArray(),
```

**My Activate method:**

```
activate = function (args) {
            getMonitorData ();
            getschedulerData (08, 09, 2014);
 },
```

Before completion of my Service call the activate method is getting returned. Here Observable array should work. But actually its not getting assign the data to my scheduler. Even though there is data in observable array.

**My Scheduler Code:**

```
        <div class="scheduler">
            <div id="scheduler" data-bind="kendoScheduler:
            {                    
                date: new Date(),
                startTime: new Date('2014/6/13 12:15 AM'),
                endTime: new Date('2014/6/13 11:54 PM'),
                height: containerHeight,
                views: [{ type: 'day', selected: true, majorTick: 15 }], //'week', //'month', //'Agenda'
                editable: false,
                useKOTemplates: true,
                eventTemplate: $('#event-template').html(), 
                allDaySlot: false,
                timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
                footer: { command: false },
                dataSource: schedulerData(),
                group: { resources: ['Monitors'] },
                resources: [{ field: 'scheduleId', name: 'Monitors', dataSource: monitorData (), title: 'Monitors' }],
                dataBound: function () { $('.k-floatwrap ul li.k-nav-current').hide(); }
            }">
            </div>
        </div>
```

If i Hard code the Data to the variable when its getting initialized, its getting worked. So there is no time interval also so the data is getting assigned to the scheduler.

Like below:

```
processMonitors = processMonitorMapper(monitors), // Functio without service call - returns hard code data

schedulerData = schedulerDataMapper(rawData), // // Functio without service call - returns hard code data
```

I came to know the observable array data will not be understand by the Kendo scheduler if its assigned after initialization of initial data. So i tried the **`ko.toJS`**. This is also not helped to me.

To avoid this kind of problem. i have tried the `ko.bindhandlers` for scheduler.

**Code:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoScheduler = {
            init: function (element) {
                var sch = $(element).data("kendoScheduler");
                console.log("Scheduler Initiated");
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                //var scheduler = $(element).data("kendoScheduler");
                //if (scheduler != null) {
                //if (value.dataSource != null && value.dataSource.length > 0 && value.resources[0] != null && value.resources[0].dataSource.length > 0) {
                //    $(element).kendoScheduler({ dataSource: value.dataSource, resources: value.resources });
                //}

                var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
                    data: value
                });
                $(element).data("kendoScheduler").setDataSource(dataSource)
                //}
                console.log("Scheduler Updated");
            }
        };
```

But the problem is the above code also not working. Kindly help me to address this above problem.

**Additional Info :** Also i need  to change the data source  & resource of scheduler, each day wise. Date will be selected via the kendo calendar. I need to call the service each day selection wise. So that new datasource need to be assigned to `Kendo Scheduler.`

How do i assign the kendo scheduler data source & resource dynamically. If i assign to the observable array its not working / not getting assigned as i said above.

**How do i write the ko.bindingHandlers for kendoScheduler Update / Init ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to write **`Ko BindHandlers`**.

I just assigned my dataSource from `getschedulerData()` method. Also when i was loading first time the Call was `async: false`. Now i made the call `sync`. So, that the `activate method will not be returned until otherwise the call get finished`.

**The below are the code i have used to replace the DataSource:**

```
                var scheduler = $('#scheduler').data('kendoScheduler');
                if (scheduler != null) {
                    var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
                        data: schedulerData()
                    });
                    scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
                }
```

But i don't know why and not sure why `observable array` didn't that work :(

Reference : [Kendo Scheduler - Click Drop Down Menus Check it out - **Configuration, Fields, Methods, Events**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-setDataSource) :)